# Tcl equivalent to a Perl one-liner

Tags: regex, tcl

I found myself using a lot of Perl one-liner regexes in my code when I need some small processing on ASCII files which I don't want to open for editing.

Is there a Tcl equivalent to this Perl one-liner command?

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/old/new/gi' filename
```

Comment: Hello all. First of all thanks for the answers. In addition I continued my own investigation and currently it looks like Tcl doesn't have the Perl one-liner equivalent as described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

look at the owh script of Richard Suchenwirth http://wiki.tcl.tk/906 which gives this sort of functionality.
Joachim

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote a Tcl script to provide Perl-like command line options. I never used it much myself -- it ended being an exercise in working with sending code to an Tcl interp. If you're interested, the code is at https://bitbucket.org/glenn_j/tcl-command-line-one-liners/src

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to execute **shell pipelines** on files in-place, but you could change `commands="$1"` to `printf '%s' "$1" > sometemporaryfile` and `sh -c "$commands"` to `tclsh sometemporaryfile`.

```
#!/bin/sh -e

# =====================================================
# filter file(s) without having to use a temporary file
# =====================================================

# EXAMPLE - remove first line and b-tags:
#   in-place 'tail -n +2 | sed "s/<[Bb]>//g"' *.html *.htm
#   # check that the commands did what you intended
#   rm *.html~ *.htm~

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  printf '%s\n' "$0: usage: in-place commands [file ...]" >&2
  exit 1
fi

commands="$1"
shift
for file; do
  cp -fp -- "$file" "$file~"
  sh -c "$commands" < "$file~" > "$file"
done
```